# Copy file from cifs mount when a file is changed

Tags: linux, debian, samba, file-copy

I have a windows XP machine, and on this i'm running a weather station.
The software updates several files in a folder.
This folder is mounted via samba on the webserver(debian)

I wan't to monitor the mounted folder, and when it detects any change, it copies this file to another location on the webserver.
some of the files changes every few seconds.

Hope i described the problem clear enough.

Rgrds Bengt

Answer (score 2):

You can make some shell scripts for doing that, but maybe the easiest way is managing to get a `rsync` process syncing the folders. Can `rsync` have some problems with NTFS, but the shell scripting solution remains.

Comment: Got any leads on how to make this script. I'm not a linux expert. Dabble abit in programming. But that is limited:)

Comment: It would be done from the Debian host. To monitor the mounted folder, you can use something like `until false; do rsync <args>; sleep <time>; done`. If `rsync` does not make it, you can combine Bash `if` and `while` sentences with the `find` command and emulate the syncing. But then take into account that before processing a document you have to be sure that it has already been completely processed by every other process that is meant to process it. For instance you should not start reading a document until the process which is creating it ends.